# Can't Pandas read multiple csv files together?

Tags: pandas

I have succeeded to read a whole directory of parquet from S3, but not CSV files. Can't pandas read all the CSV files located in the path to the S3 directory?

Comment: No it's not possible but you can use a comprehension to read the files individually then concatenate them with `pd.concat`

Comment: Just came across your question but don't have time to formulate a good answer right now. But definitely check this: https://pypi.org/project/awswrangler/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, csv is not readable.
But I think you can run csv separately using the loop, sth like:

```
csv_files = your_csv files

for csv_file in cs`enter code here`v_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f's3://{bucket_name}/{csv_file}')
    dfs.append(df)
```